# get no output from hmac function

Tags: php, hmac

I want to use hmac to authenticate a user by email
The hmac will be stored in the database along with the userid.

- Do I also need to store the `$payload` for decryption as well?

Am I doing it right?

I don't get any string in the url querystring?

This is my testpage with the following

```
$secret = "dfjhglkhniuh65645";
$payload= "234|somedata";

$hmac = hash_hmac("sha2", $payload, $secret, true);
//$hmac = base64_encode($hmac);
if (! function_exists("hash_hmac")) {
    echo "hmac function does not exist";
}
$uri="test.php?hash=$hmac";

if(!isset($_GET['hash'])){
    header('location: ' . $uri);
    exit();
}
echo "testpage<br><br>";
if(isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash']))
{
    $sig = $_GET['hash'];
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac("sha2", $payload, $secret, true);
    if($expected_sig === $sig)echo "verification succeeded";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the possible values for hashing algorithms. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php

I moved your code a little bit, and got rid of the raw output for hash_hmac (not sure why you wanted that) and it works for me.

```
<?php

if (!function_exists("hash_hmac")) {
    echo "hmac function does not exist";
    die();
}

$secret = "dfjhglkhniuh65645";
$payload = "234|somedata";

$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret);
$uri = "test.php?hash=$hmac";

if (!isset($_GET['hash'])) {
    header('location: ' . $uri);
    exit();
}

echo "testpage<br><br>";
if (isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])) {
    $sig = $_GET['hash'];
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac("sha256", $payload, $secret);
    if ($expected_sig === $sig) {
        echo "verification succeeded";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but do you also have to save the payload, is it in the docs?